# How can I make an NSImage into a button

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to make it so that the user can click on an NSImage and trigger an action? How can I do this, through Interface Builder or programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah:

```
[myButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"mypng.png"]];
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not able to connect outlets to buttons I am making in IB. Why might that be?

Comment: @Regan: That's another question.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it was because I hadn't changed the outlets from NSImage outlets to NSButton ones.